# How allocate_shared works?

Tags: c++, c++11

From [std::allocate_shared in cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared):

> Constructs an object of type `T` and wraps it in a `std::shared_ptr` using `args` as the parameter list for the constructor of `T`. The object is constructed as if by the expression `::new (pv) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`, where `pv` is an internal `void*` pointer to storage suitable to hold an object of type `T`. The storage is typically larger than `sizeof(T)` in order to use one allocation for both the control block of the shared pointer and the `T` object.
>
> All memory allocation is done using a copy of `alloc`, which must satisfy the `Allocator` requirements.

What make me confused is, think about following user-defined allocator, also from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator)

```
template <class T>
struct Mallocator {
    typedef T value_type;
    Mallocator() = default;
    template <class U> Mallocator(const Mallocator<U>&) {}
    T* allocate(std::size_t n) { return static_cast<T*>(std::malloc(n * sizeof(T))); }
    void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t) { std::free(p); }
};
template <class T, class U>
bool operator==(const Mallocator<T>&, const Mallocator<U>&) { return true; }
template <class T, class U>
bool operator!=(const Mallocator<T>&, const Mallocator<U>&) { return false; }
```

Since `Mallocator` can only allocate memory of `sizeof(T)`, how could `allocate_shared` allocate a storage which larger than `sizeof(T)` in order to use one allocation for both the control block of the shared pointer and the `T` object?

Comment: It could allocate 2*sizeof(T), but I don't know whether it actually does that.

Comment: @immibis That might not work so well when T=char ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a two part answer.  First I will address what it reasonably could do, then I will explain how.

The goal is to allocate a control block and the room for a `T` within the same allocation.  This can be done with an internal template struct, like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct shared_ptr_allocation {
    shared_ptr_control_block cb;
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T)>::type storage;
};
```

(Assuming the presence of an internal `shared_ptr_control_block` type.  I don't believe the standard requires any specific structure to be used, this is just an example and may or may not be suitable for an actual implementation.)

So all `std::allocate_shared()` needs to do is allocate a `shared_ptr_allocation<T>` and it gets both the control block *and* the `T` storage, which will be initialized with a placement-new later.

---

But how do we obtain an allocator suitable to allocate this struct?  This, I believe is the crux of your question, and the answer is quite simple: `std::allocator_traits`.

This trait has a `rebind_alloc` template member, which can be used to obtain an allocator of a different type, which is constructed from your own allocator.  For example, the first few lines of `allocate_shared` might look like:

```
template<class T, class Alloc, class... Args>
shared_ptr<T> allocate_shared(const Alloc& alloc, Args&&... args)
{
    using control_block_allocator_t =
        typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>
                    ::rebind_other<shared_ptr_control_block<T>>;

    control_block_allocator_t control_block_allocator(alloc);

    // And so on...
}
```

And `control_block_allocator` is used to perform the actual allocation.

Check [this sample](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e03b1dc44fdd532) where we display the name of the `T` type when an allocation is performed, and then use `std::allocate_shared` to allocate an `int`.  Where the mangled type name of `int` is `i`, the mangled type name of what we're allocating is `St23_Sp_counted_ptr_inplaceIi10MallocatorIiELN9__gnu_cxx12_Lock_policyE2EE`.  Clearly we're allocating something different!

---

Aside: we can confirm this by forward-declaring an allocator template and specializing it for one type, basically leaving the other specializations without a definition and therefore incomplete.  The compiler should throw a fit when we try to `allocate_shared` with that allocator, and behold, [it does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/707cce102700bff5)!

> `error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'OnlyIntAllocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<int, OnlyIntAllocator<int>, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy::_S_atomic> >'`

So, in this implementation, `std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace` is the template struct that holds both the control block and the object storage.

---

Now, to address how rebinding actually manages to work in practice, there's two key requirements here and this really simple allocator meets both of them.  First, we need `std::allocator_traits<...>::rebind_other<...>` to actually work.  From [the docs cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits):

> `rebind_alloc<T>`: `Alloc::rebind<T>::other` if present, otherwise `Alloc<T, Args>` if this `Alloc` is `Alloc<U, Args>`

Since this example type doesn't have a `rebind` template member, this rebind template simply strips the template arguments off of `Mallocator<whatever>` and replaces `whatever` with the new type (preserving the following template arguments, if any -- in this case there are none).

But why construct the new allocator with the old, and how is that expected to work?  That's covered on the [same page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) you linked to yourself:

> `A a(b)`: Constructs `a` such that `B(a)==b` and `A(b)==a`. Does not throw exceptions. (Note: this implies that all allocators related by rebind maintain each other's resources, such as memory pools)

Comment: Very thanks! I got it. So if I want to implement a pool with T, I need to pre-allocate a group of memory which size is sizeof(internal_type<T>), and since I do not know what the internal type it is, maybe I can use sizeof(T)+32?

Comment: @alpha If you wanted to be evil, you could do something [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7fefd18c896f50b) to detect the size.

Comment: I got it. I can call a dummy allocate_shared once in program init function to get the size and then allocate a group of memory.